# How to make sidebar horizontal for xs devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, sidebar

I'm using the default CSS that came with bootstrap; also using the bootstrap theme and dashboard CSS.

By default, when on xs devices, the sidebar disappears. Well, this is what i'm using for all my application's main navigation. So, I'd like for it to switch to a horizontal layout on such devices, but I can't find anything online about how to do this.

I scoured the documentation, but it's pretty lousy IMO. There should be a breakdown of all the classes and their uses. I imagine there's a class i can add that will do what I want.

Does anyone know it?

Here's the html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 overflow-fix">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li class="icon-center">
          <a href="/admin" ><i class="fa fa-tasks fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Recent Activity"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="icon-center">
          <a href="/admin/users"><i class="fa fa-users fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Users"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="icon-center">
          <a href="/admin/accounts"><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Accounts"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="icon-center">
          <a href="/admin/branches"><i class="fa fa-sitemap fa-2x" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Branches"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the .css files actually have pretty good comments so I was able to see that .sidebar class had display:none; on it. Then found the media query right under it which gets activated when on larger view ports.

Added the below to my overriding css file, and now it changes to horizontal centered menu when on small screens, then pops back to the sidebar on large screens.

```
.sidebar {
  display:block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.sidebar ul {
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:0px;
}

.sidebar ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .sidebar ul li{
    display:block;
  }
}
```

I'm quite new to messing with CSS, so if anyone has a suggestion for how better to format the above code, please don't hesitate to share!

Answer (score 0):

The sidebar has display: none by default. This can be overriden by

```
.sidebar
{
    display:block;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    border-right: 1px solid #eee;
}
```